# gitosis with password authentication (don't want to use ssh-key)

Tags: passwords, git, authentication

I followed an online tutorial to setup gitosis on my LAN server and it's using ssh-key to authenticate now. All the tutorials I saw were using ssh-key authentication. I was wondering if I can use password to authenticate a remote clone or push?

The reason I want to do this is because there are many machines in my LAN, and I don't want to setup ssh-key from each machine, so it may be easier to just remember one password.

One problem I can see with password authentication. If the gitosis need to authenticate per file, then this will be a pain to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but it requires for a process :

- listening for your git requests
- making the authentication
- passing that request to the gitolite script.

Since you don't want ssh-based authentication, that means no ssh-daemon.
That leaves you with an Apache httpd process, which you can easily configure (git or not git) to authenticate against:

- a file
- an LDAP
- ...

In the `VirtualDirectory` you will define, you will then call the gitosis script, that you have to modify for it, in turn, calling the **[`git http-backend`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html)** (the "smart http" cgi script).

I didn't test it with the quite old and obsolete [gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis).
But it works just fine with **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**: see **[how to setup gitolite to use smart http mode](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/http-backend.html)**

Comment: Interesting! I never heard of gitolite, I have to try it out... I was wondering why the gitosis stoped maintaining after 2009 and yet there is still not a replacement. I mush just miss the successor.